# PHP and MySQLi CRUD with LEFT JOIN tables

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

Is there a way I can create PHP and MySQLi CRUD with LEFT JOIN tables. Currently, I have 4 tables - fee, payments, class and students. The user should be able to create, edit and delete the data in payments table. However, the rows for payments are limited - (payments_id, student_id, payment_date, payment_amount and fee_id). Hence, I want the user able to select user firstname instead of the student_id.

Currently, I modified the php code and encountered several errors.

```
var $query3 = 'SELECT students.student_id, fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description, fee.class_id, fee.fee_amount, 
                    students.firstname, students.lastname, payments.payment_id, payments.payment_date, 
                    class.class_description, payments.payment_amount, payments.payment_date
                    FROM students
                    LEFT JOIN class ON students.class_id = class.class_id
                    LEFT JOIN fee ON fee.class_id = class.class_id
                    LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.student_id
                    AND Payments.fee_id = fee.fee_id';

    public function createPayments($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,  "INSERT INTO $this->query3 (
                                                    student_id, fee_id, fee_description, class_id, fee_amount,
                                                    firstname, lastname, payment_id, payment_date,
                                                    class_description, payment_amount, payment_date)
                                                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issi', $item->student_id, $item->fee_id, $item-> fee_description, $item->class_id, $item->fee_amount,
                                $item->firstname, $item->lastname, $item->payment_id, $item->payment_date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
                                $item->class_description, $item->payment_amount, $item->payment_date);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        $autoid = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);

        return $autoid;
    }

    /**
     * Updates the passed item in the table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * @param stdClass $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function updatePayments($item) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "UPDATE $this->query3 SET student_id=?, fee_id=?, fee_description=?, class_id=?, fee_amount=?,
                                                    firstname=?, lastname=?, payment_date=?, class_description=?, payment_amount=?,
                                                    payment_date=? where payment_id=?");        
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'issii',  $item->student_id, $item->fee_id, $item-> fee_description, $item->class_id, $item->fee_amount,
                                $item->firstname, $item->lastname, $item->payment_id, $item->payment_date->toString('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 
                                $item->class_description, $item->payment_amount, $item->payment_date);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the item corresponding to the passed primary key value from 
     * the table.
     *
     * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
     *
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function deletePayments($itemID) {

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "DELETE FROM $this->query3 WHERE payment_id = ?");
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $itemID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $this->throwExceptionOnError();

        mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);     
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
    }
```

**Error Code**

```
There was an error while invoking the operation. Check your server settings and try invoking the operation again. 

Reason: Server error MySQL Error - 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT students.student_id, fee.fee_id, fee.fee_description, fee.class_id, fee.f' at line 1 #0 C:\wamp\www\feez3\services\PaymentsService2.php(220): PaymentsService2->throwExceptionOnError() #1 [internal function]: PaymentsService2->deletePayments('Enter Value') #2 [internal function]: ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(PaymentsService2), Array) #3 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Server\Reflection\Function\Abstract.php(380): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php(359): Zend_Server_Reflection_Function_Abstract->__call('invokeArgs', Array) #5 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php(359): Zend_Server_Reflection_Method->invokeArgs(Object(PaymentsService2), Array) #6 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php(553): Zend_Amf_Server->_dispatch('deletePayments', Array, 'PaymentsService...') #7 C:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php(629): Zend_Amf_Server->_handle(Object(Zend_Amf_Request_Http)) #8 C:\wamp\www\feez3\gateway.php(69): Zend_Amf_Server->handle() #9 {main}
```

Can anyone guide me thru this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: AND Payments.fee_id = fee.fee_id shouldn't it be payments.

Comment: Database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. Anyway, I like short and meaningful alias for complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the query, so I just wrote the query how I would write it. Maybe give this a try.

```
"SELECT   s.student_id, 
          s.firstname,
          s.lastname,
          f.fee_id, 
          f.fee_description, 
          f.class_id, 
          f.fee_amount, 
          p.payment_id, 
          p.payment_date, 
          p.payment_amount, 
          p.payment_date,
          c.class_description
FROM      students s 
LEFT JOIN class c ON (s.class_id = c.class_id)
LEFT JOIN fee f ON (c.class_id = f.class_id)
LEFT JOIN payments p ON (s.student_id = p.student_id)  
AND       p.fee_id = f.fee_id";
```

Keeping it in double quotes...
Good luck! :-)